# Filter dataframe by vector of column names and constant column names

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

This is surely easy but for the life of me I can't find the right syntax.

I want to keep all "ID_" columns, regardless of the number of columns and the numbers attached, and keep other columns by constant name.

Something like the below command that doesn't work (on the recreated data, every time):

```
###Does not work, but shows what I am trying to do
testdf1 <- df1[,c(paste(idvec, collapse="','"),"ConstantNames_YESwant")]
```

Recreated data:

```
rand <- sample(1:2, 1)
if(rand==1){
  df1 <- data.frame(
    ID_0=0,
    ID_1=1,
    ID_2=11,
    ID_3=111,
    LotsOfColumnsWithVariousNames_NOwant="unwanted_data",
    ConstantNames_YESwant="wanted_data",
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  desired.df1 <- data.frame(
    ID_0=0,
    ID_1=1,
    ID_2=11,
    ID_3=111,
    ConstantNames_YESwant="wanted_data",
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}
if(rand==2){
  df1 <- data.frame(
    ID_0=0,
    ID_1=1,
    LotsOfColumnsWithVariousNames_NOwant="unwanted_data",
    ConstantNames_YESwant="wanted_data",
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  desired.df1 <- data.frame(
    ID_0=0,
    ID_1=1,
    ConstantNames_YESwant="wanted_data",
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
}
```

Comment: what is `idvec`?

Comment: The ID names, I was playing with grepl to cut the ID's  ` justid <- df[ ,  grepl( "ID_" , colnames( df ) ) ]` but couldn't get it to go with the other named cols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R , you could do

```
#Get all the ID columns
idvec <- grep("ID", colnames(df1), value = TRUE)
#Select ID columns and the constant names you want. 
df1[c(idvec, "ConstantNames_YESwant")]

#  ID_0 ID_1 ConstantNames_YESwant
#1    0    1           wanted_data
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  select(matches("ID_*"), ConstantNames_YESwant)

df1 %>% 
  select(starts_with("ID"), ConstantNames_YESwant)

# ID_0 ID_1 ConstantNames_YESwant
# 1    0    1           wanted_data
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for. Nice dplyr pipe, good call. You can also just library(dplyr). Thanks for this!